# Number of ways to separate $n$ points in the plane

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Say you are given $n$ points such that no three are colinear. Show the number of ways to separate them into two subsets by drawing a straight line depends on $n$ but not the position of the points.

Comment: Probably one should seek a one-to-one correspondence between two arbitrary sets of points with no three colinear in a way that makes every set split off from one of them by a straight line corresponds to a set split off from the other by a straight line. One could wonder how many correspondences exist for a given pair of sets of $n$ points and whether that number is the same for all such pairs of sets of $n$ points. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy : I'm not convinced it is true. take 4 points. if it is a  triangle with the 4th point inside, there are $6$ ways to separate them. if it is a square, there are $8$ ways to separate them.

Comment: @user1952009 : What are the eight ways to separate the square?  I count seven if you include the non-separation.  Either (1) You put all four points on one side of the line, or (2) you separate just one point from the others, and there are four ways to do that, or (3) you separate two points from the other two, and there are just two ways to do that.  That makes seven. With the triangle with the fourth point in the interior, either (1) you put all four points on one side of the line, or (2) you separate one point from the others, and there are three ways to do that, or (3) you separate$\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots$ two from the other two, and there are three ways to do that. So with either configuration, there are seven. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: However, the proposal in my comment, for a way to prove the proposed result, is wrong, and your example is a counterexample to that. $\qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy : you are right, so sorry. however, that theorem if true is really really (really) counter-intuitive. I guess the argument should be that displacing a point from the convex hull to the interior (and conversely ) doesn't change the number of way to separate them ?

Comment: The result is a theorem, that I know for sure. Now, with combinatorics we can see that in the case of 4 points, there will be 8 ways to divide them into 2 subsets (including the empty separation with all points in one side). For the case of the square one of them is impossible with a straight line, namely dividing it into diagonals. For the triangle, one is impossible as well,  separating the middle point form the vertices of the triangle. The theorem holds in general.

Comment: There are $\binom n 2$ unordered pairs of points in the set and thus $\binom n 2$ lines between them. Calling two of the points $A$ and $B$ a small perturbation of the line between them can have of any of four positions: it can put $A$ and $B$ south of it, or $A$ and $B$ north of it, or $A$ south of it and $B$ north of it, or $A$ north of it and $B$ south of it.  This gives us four partitions of the whole set of $n$ points.  Any third point $C$ is on one side of the line through $A$ and $B$.  I would try to show that${}\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$moving $C$ to the other side of the line through $A$ and $B$ does not change the _number_ of ways to separate the sets, even though it may result in a set of partitions not isomorphic to what it was before $C$ crossed that line. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let there be $k$ oriented lines that divide the $n$ points into different left and right sides.

There are $2$ trivial lines and $k-2$ nontrivial lines. Let each nontrivial line swing counter-clockwise as far as it can, until it hits two of the points. The nontrivial lines will match with the ordered pairs of the points, of which there are $n(n-1)$. So $k=n^2-n+2$.

Or, if you want to disregard orientation, divide by two! $\frac{k}{2}=\binom{n}{2}+1$.

Comment: to be really convinced I need more details : a non-trivial separating line separates the set of points into two non-empty sets, each having a convex hull $A$ and $B$. the line stops swinging after it has hit a point $\in A$ and another $\in B$. the experience shows that for a given separating line, there are only two (at most two ? always two ?) positions where it can stop swinging. and because no $3$ points are aligned, for every couple of point, there are (always?) two different separating lines which can stop swinging by hitting those two points.