# Given n distinguishable d-dimensional points what is the largest number of different ways they can be linearly separated?

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Suppose we have $n$ distinguishable points in $\mathbb{R}^d$. What is $f(n, d)$, the largest number of different ways we can separate them using a single hyperplane? I don't consider swapping the 'left' and 'right' side of the plane to be different.

I found the [following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1640777/number-of-ways-to-separate-n-points-in-the-plane) for the $d = 2$ case, so $f(n, 2) = \binom{n}{2} + 1$.

You may assume that the points are in a position allowing the most number of separations. For $d = 2$ it is shown this doesn't matter (beyond no collinearity), but I don't know if this also holds for higher dimensions (with points in general position).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the $n$ points in [general position](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position), as shown in the paper ["The number of partitions of a set of N points in k dimensions induced by hyperplanes"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/number-of-partitions-of-a-set-of-n-points-in-k-dimensions-induced-by-hyperplanes/54B3043D7F8445D130FE7D60295FAE6B) by E. F. Harding, the function you are looking for is:

$$f(n,d) = \sum_{k=0}^{d}{n-1 \choose k}$$